# Web flow with Angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am managing an Enterprise application with UI developed in Angular. There is a requirement to implement a "web flow" like consumer registration with 5-6 screens capturing different set of information before registering consumers. We also need to store the consumer information temporarily between the pages, so that consumer can edit previously entered information.

My question is - Does Angular 2 provides a way to manage the "web flow" like development? And how does it store the information temporarily between the pages, so that consumers can navigate back and forth between the screens to edit the details (if, needed)? Since this is consumer enrollment flow, there will be consumers PII involved, and we require a safe way to store it while consumer navigate across the screens. if needed, we can store it on the server side too.. however, I'm trying to find out from experts if Angular does allow this on the CLient side?

Comment: Each screen is a separate component ?

Comment: Yes.. They are different components

Comment: I believe, each component has a separate form group, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this feels more like a step-form more than actual different pages, a step form will keep its data when you are moving between steps however in both cases data will not persist if you reload the page in that situation you will most likely want to store each step data in either `localStorage` or in a client side DB like `indexedDB` or `sqlite` or even in your own backend service if you are afraid of the users clearing their cache and also the stored data with it and you will need to check out if there are any data stored when you first enter the page as well.